# Error installing WSO2Cep2.1.0 on WSO2Carbon4.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

I tried installing WSO2Cep2.1.0 as a feature on WSO2Carbon4.2.0 platform. By looking at [Release Matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/), I see that CEP2.1.0 is at repository 4.0.7. On WSO2Carbon, I select the related repository and then WSO2Cep and then I click install. The error below is produced.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. 
Software being installed: WSO2 Carbon - Data Bridge - Data Publisher Aggregate Feature 4.0.7 (org.wso2.carbon.databridge.datapublisher.feature.group 4.0.7) 
Software currently installed: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group 4.2.0) 
Only one of the following can be installed at once: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.0.0 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar 4.0.0) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar 4.2.0) WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.0.6 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar 4.0.6) 
Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.0.6 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group 4.0.6) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group [4.0.6] 
Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group 4.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group [4.2.0] 
Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.0.6 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 4.0.6) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar [4.0.6] 
Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 4.2.0) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar [4.2.0] 
Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Data Bridge - Data Publisher Aggregate Feature 4.0.7 (org.wso2.carbon.databridge.datapublisher.feature.group 4.0.7) To: org.wso2.carbon.core.feature.group [4.0.5,4.1.0)
```

This is not meaningful to me. How can I accomplish the installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Ragavan's answer, if you need to install CEP 2.1.0 features, you need to have a Carbon 4.0.x kernel (Carbon kernel has the bare bones carbon server, or simply Carbon). The above error is coming because the related CEP features for CEP 2.1.0 depend on carbon kernel components with 4.0.x versions and the carbon 4.2.0 kernel components conflict with them.

You would not be able to add CEP 2.1.0 features to a Carbon 4.2.0 server. However, you can install CEP 2.1.0 features on top of ESB 4.6.0, vice versa or install both product features on a Carbon 4.0.x kernel.

CEP 3.0.0 which is based on Carbon 4.2.0 is already released. However, if you want to install ESB features as well, you would need to wait for ESB 4.8.0 which is the ESB version that is based on Carbon 4.2.0. ESB 4.8.0 is due to be released in about a week. You can find the RC1 pack [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/shafreen/20131128/wso2esb-4.8.0.zip) and the relevant P2-repo [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/shafreen/20131129_FINAL/p2-repo.zip).

Answer (score 0):

You can't install CEP 2.1.0 on Carbon 4.2.0. As you see in Release Matrix CEP 2.1.0 is released on carbon 4.0.7. CEP for Carbon 4.2.0 will be released soon.

Comment: Since ESB4.6.0 was released on Carbon4.0.6 and CEP2.1.0 was released on Carbon4.0.7, I cannot install ESB4.6.0 and CEP2.1.0 on a single carbon, can I?

Comment: You can. 4.x are the major version releases.

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't Carbon4.2.o major release?

Comment: Sorry it is not major version. But between 4.0.0 and 4.2.0 apis may have changed.